# Can We accept the PDF integrated to 1 with negative probability values as a legitimated PDF?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have got the two below Plot using Mathematica Code , However I have got the PDF integrated to 1 , I have got the first Plot Over $\mathbb{R+}$(Support), But when we look the plot we see the pole oriented to the negative region (Negative probability) , And the second Plot For the same PDF over $\mathbb{R}$, But it  started from negative probability values , Now my question here : Can We accept the PDF integrated to 1 with negative probability values as a legitimated  PDF ?.

Really am confused that there is a negative probability and its widely used in Quantum Mechanics From [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_probability)
[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAi1a.png)

[image]

Comment: I would not accept this as a legitimate probability density under the standard theory.